# Encapsular de código jquery o separarlo en distintas librerías

Tags: javascript, jquery

soy novato en este campo (estudiante de 2ºDAW), me gustaría optimizar lo máximo los recursos y me estoy armando un lió con el tema. Estoy desarrollando el proyecto de final de curso algo grande en el que tengo una pagina web con distintas secciones (cada una con un html/ventana propio) en las cuales se pueden  realizar distintas acciones sobre varias bases de datos (insertar, modificar, listar, borrar,...). Todas los eventos los controlo en un único archivo js, por lo que al final me va a quedar un js muy grande en el cual según en la sección en la que se este de la web va a ver código "muerto", mis dudas son:

-Creo una librería de js, separando y aislando las funciones especificas que afecten a dicha sección de la web aislando el resto y solo cargando los js necesarios?

-Actualmente dentro de la función "$(function () {" tengo los eventos de escucha de botones, que ejecutan un Ajax . Mi duda aquí viene si es recomendable encapsular el ajax en  una función aparte fuera del  "$(function () {", haciendo la llamada a dicha función cuando se produzca el evento correspondiente.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.
un saludo

Comment: Hola! Lo ideal sí sería separar tus archivos .js por módulo, esto para que sea más fácil manterlo en el futuro. Algo que hacía cuando usaba jquery era poner el código dentro de una IIFE para evitar la colisión de nombres.
Puedes leer este post en español, estoy seguro que te servirá de ayuda. 
https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/jquery/capitulo-10.html
https://programacionymas.com/blog/funciones-javascript-invocadas-inmediatamente-IIFE

Comment: Gracias por contestar, e leído los enlaces que me has pasado y realmente desconocía el IIFE. E separado las partes que son genéricas (afectan a cualquier pagina) y las e metido en un js aparte con funciones IIFE. Muchas gracias por tus consejos, vengo de programar en java donde encapsulaba todo lo que era posible pero en jquery me perdia con el tema.